# Template helper gets called multiple times

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

My intention is to retrieve one random entry from a collection and display it on the website - if all sentences are through (read: the user has "seen" them), display something else (therefore a dummy sentence gets returned). But, on server start and on button-click events, this helper gets fired at least twice. Here is some code:

In client.js:

```
Template.registerHelper('random_sentence', function() {
  fetched = _.shuffle(Sentences.find({
    users: {
      $nin: [this.userId]
    }
  }).fetch())[0];
  if (fetched === undefined) {
    return {
      sentence: "done",
      _id: 0,
      done: true
    };
  }
  Session.set('question', fetched._id);
  console.log(fetched);
  return fetched;
  });
```

The helper function for the template:

```
sent: function(){
  sent = Session.get('question');
  return Sentences.findOne(sent);
}
```

in main template:

```
{{#with random_sentence}}
  {{#if done}}
    <!-- Display something else -->
  {{else}}
    <div class="container">
      {{> question}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

the "question" template:

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
    <h3>{{sent.sentence}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I don't return anything in the "random_sentences"-function,nothing get's displayed.

I don't know where my "logic failure" is situated? I'm new to meteor - so I might overlook something obvious.

Thanks in advance :-)

UPDATE: This is how I intended to get the new sentence and display it:

```
Template.answer.events({
  'click': function(event) {
    var text = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    if (text !== null) {
      var question = Session.get('question');
      var setModifier = {
        $inc: {}
      };
    setModifier.$inc[text] = 1;
    Sentences.update(question, setModifier);
    Meteor.call('update_user', question);
    Notifications.success('Danke!', 'Deine Beurteilung wurde gespeichert.');
    Blaze.render(Template.question, document.head);
    }
  }
});
```

In server.js (updating the question and a counter on the user):

```
Meteor.methods({
  update_user: function(question) {
    Sentences.update(question, {
      $push: {
        "users": this.userId
      }
    });
    Meteor.users.update({
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      $inc: {
        "profile.counter": 1
      }
    });
  },
});
```

I found the Blaze.render function somewhere on the web. the "document.head" part is simply because this function needs a DOM Element to render to, and since document.body just "multiplies" the body, I ust moved it to the head. (DOM logic isn't my strong part).

An Idea I had: would it make the whole idea simpler to implement with iron-router? atm. I wanted to create a "one-page app" - I therefore thought that I don't need a router there.

Another problem: Getting this logic to work (User gets one random sentence, which he has not seen) and publishing small sets of the collection (so the Client don't have to download 5 MB of data before using).

Answer (score 0):

Template helpers can be called multiple times so it's good to avoid making them stateful. You're better off selecting the random entry in an *onCreated* or *onRendered* [template handler.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) There you can do your random select, update the state, and put your choice in a Session variable to be retrieved by the helper.

Comment: Thank you, problem now is, it works (it get's called only once) but the Logic somehow doesn't apply - the whole "Current user not in Users Array" part is somehow not working? e.g. I get a sentence multiple time (even though in the now onRendered it should create a new resultset consisting of sentences which this user has not seen.

Comment: You're not showing the code where you move from sentence to sentence or where you update the sentence as read.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do atm. I updated the question.